MDB cashless device not switch to 32-bit mode
MDB 4.3. Cashless device. I am trying to switch my device to 32 bit mode in order to use the vend request command with a 4 bit price.
To do this I use the Expansion Enable Options command and enable 32-bit mode there by manually forming bytes from bits.
c# code
And after that I try to use a 32 bit vend request command with a price of 4 bytes, but for some reason the device uses a 16 bit vend request command.
